# How to select data of table A in one record with additional columns from table B filled with data from table C

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine, pivot

I have Table A which has a relation "OneToMany" to Table C.
Table B is also related to the Table C. What I want is to get all the data from Table A merged with all ids of Table B as a column name(1-3 in this example) filled with correct data of Table B from Table C from column "value".

This is the simplest scenario I can imagine right now, where (x, y, z, j, k, l, m) can be anything and where (a, b, c) are just column names of Table A

```
Table A:
ID - a - b - c 
--------------
1  - x - y - z    
2  - x - y - z
3  - x - y - z

Table B:
ID
--
1
2
3

Table C:
ID - Table A (FK) - Table B (FK) - value 
------------------------------------------
1  - 1            - 1              - j
2  - 1            - 2              - k  
3  - 1            - 3              - l
4  - 2            - 1              - m


Expected result
ID - a - b - c    - B1   - B2   - B3     (B1 means Table B with id 1 which should be column name)
-------------------------------------
1  - x - y - z    - j    - k    - l        ("j" for example is Value from Table C where Table A is 1 and Table B is 1 as well)
2  - x - y - z    - m    - NULL - NULL
3  - x - y - z    - NULL - NULL - NULL
```

My dream query is:

```
select A.*, GET_ALL_IDS_AS_COLUMN_NAME_FROM_TABLE(B) from A SOMEHOW FILL DOES COLUMNS FROM B BY C BY THIS <MAGIC> CONDITION WHERE C.A = A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    a.id,
    a.a,
    a.b,
    a.c,
    max(case when b.id = 1 then c.value end) b1,
    max(case when b.id = 2 then c.value end) b1,
    max(case when b.id = 3 then c.value end) b1,
from a
cross join b
left join c on c.id_a = a.id and c.id_b = b.id
group by 
    a.id,
    a.a,
    a.b,
    a.c
```

Note that it would be simpler to concatenate all values from table C instead of spreading them over several columns:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (
        select group_concat(c.value order by b.id delimiter '-' )
        from b
        inner join c on c.id_a = a.id and c.id_b = b.id
    ) b_values
from a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select a.*, c.b_1, c.b_2, c.b_3
from a left join
     (select c.id_a,
             max(case when b_id = 1 then value end) as b_1,
             max(case when b_id = 2 then value end) as b_2,
             max(case when b_id = 3 then value end) as b_3
      from c
      group by c.id_a
     ) c
     on c.id_a = a.id;
```

But, if you want this *dynamic*, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to construct the pivot.